# Are kernel32.dll and shell32.dll supported in ARM?

Tags: winapi, arm, kernel32, windows-rt

I've a Metro App (C#) which is running fine on ARM (Surface), but a component is not working on ARM, when I checked my app compatibility on **Windows App Cert Kits** its showing this:

```
AreFileApisANSI , CopyFileW , CreateFileMappingW , CreateFileW , CreateMutexW , CreateThread , ExitProcess , ExitThread , FatalAppExitA , FindFirstFileW , FreeEnvironmentStringsW , GetACP , GetCommandLineA , GetConsoleCP , GetConsoleMode , GetCurrentDirectoryW , GetDriveTypeW , GetEnvironmentStringsW , GetFileAttributesW , GetFileSize , GetFileType , GetFullPathNameA , GetFullPathNameW , GetModuleFileNameA , GetModuleFileNameW , GetModuleHandleExW , GetModuleHandleW , GetOEMCP , GetStartupInfoW , GetStdHandle , GetSystemInfo , GetTempFileNameW , GetTempPathW , GetTickCount , HeapQueryInformation , HeapValidate , InitializeCriticalSection , InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount , LoadLibraryExW , LoadLibraryW , LocalFree , MapViewOfFile , MoveFileW , OpenFileMappingW , OutputDebugStringA , ReadConsoleW , RtlUnwind , SetConsoleCtrlHandler , SetCurrentDirectoryW , SetFilePointer , SetStdHandle , SetUnhandledExceptionFilter , Sleep , TerminateProcess , UnhandledExceptionFilter , WaitForSingleObject , WriteConsoleW , lstrlenA
```

These all the *kernel32.dll* functions are **not** supported for this application type *MyLib.dll*, and

```
SHGetSpecialFolderPathW in shell32.dll is not supported for this application type
```

while running on **ARM**.

*Is there any alternative/equivalent lib for ARM? If it is please let me know.*

Thanks in Advance

Prashant

Comment: Nope, you cannot call those functions on ARM. No alternatives. Stop calling those functions.

Comment: Thank you David.
No work around !!
Or Do I need to write a fresh component for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call those functions on ARM. They are simply not available. In fact many of the functions aren't available even on the Intel Windows RT. For example, consider [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366537.aspx). The documentation states clearly that this function is available on desktop apps only.

You'll have to find a way to live without these functions.